# How to process mysql_result data before AMFPHP passes data to Flash

Tags: php, mysql, amfphp

How can I iterate through a MySql result before `AMFPHP` passes the data to Flash?

When Flash calls the service the following code gets the data

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT file_type, file_name ..
$result = mysql_query($sql);
return $result;
```

Then I assume AMFPHP processes this result resource.

For each file_name retrieved I need to run a function to create a new file_name and pass the new updated data to Flash - the new filename expires so I need to do this at run time rather than changing the filenames in the database.

Comment: Your question does not show any effort. have you wrote any code to iterate through the result set? its same  php code, nothing special in amfphp

Comment: do you want to return the result set with modified FILE_NAME column?

Answer (score 1):

How are you providing your data to AMFPHP? Why do you need to iterate through the result before sending it? I'm asking this because maybe you could do your processing while executing your query.